# Saving excel file as xml data

Tags: xml, excel, schema, vba

Long story short, I have an XML file with some bulk data I've exported from an unnamed program.  The only way I know how to get what I need out of the data is to use VBA.  So I've treated the data with VBA and now I need to convert the file back to XML but can't save it this way in Excel.  Excel says,

"Cannot save XML data because the workbook does not contain any XML mappings"

Is this the same as an XML schema?

If so, is there a way I can create one from a copy of the exported file?

I apologize if this is a repeat of a question somewhere else, I've been searching all day and haven't found anything that helps.  I'll click solved or whatever I have to do if there happens to be a thread somewhere else with the answer.  Thanks for any help!

Dan

Comment: You can't use the VBA FileSave or FileSaveAs command to create an XML document.  If you've modified the XML data using Excel, you'll need to get the data out of Excel, and back into XML using more VBA code.

Comment: If thats the case how come there is a xml data save option?  Ill have to do some digging to find out how to code this.

Comment: Excel has it's own XML format, which is a totally different XML than your custom XML.

Comment: Very good.  Any suggestions one where to start with macros?

Comment: Does the data in Excel still have all the tags and original XML type formatting?  Then try copying it to a text editor and saving with XML extension?  If it doesn't then you'll need to [map the XML data](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/xml.html) and then probably adjust the output to meet your needs.

Comment: It has a row of cells above each column with words similar to the tags in the text file...for example:

Comment: The fourth line in the xml file reads "<language_id>120</language_id>"  and the excel file has /header/language_id with 86 rows underneath with the number 120

Comment: Is that what you mean?

Comment: I THINK I solved this.  If anyone cares for an answer (ill find out if it worked tuesday), let me know.  Ill edit it into something that I can disclose....

Answer (score 0):

So...I opened the original xml export file as a text and then had vba copy and paste the requisite data from the cells in the xls file such that the text files from xml export and vba export structure and tags are exactly the same, then added the file extension .xml.  What are the chances the xml files are identical?